# Android:Unable to insert Arraylist values in database

Tags: android, database, arraylist, android-asynctask

i parsed a json string and stored the values in a arraylist, now i wanna put this values in database, which iam doing the async task onbackground method as below:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> budget_val = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 HashMap<String, String> budget_Val_map = new HashMap<String, String>();

     budget_Val_map.put(PRODUCT_CAKE, cake);
     budget_Val_map.put(PRODUCT_YEASTEXTRACT, yeastextract);
     budget_Val_map.put(PRODUCT_BIFLAVOURS, biflavours);
     budget_Val_map.put(PRODUCT_YEASTNUTRIFERM, yeastnutriferm);
budget_val.add(budget_Val_map);

   dbHelper.open();
   dbHelper.topinchartsRecord(new ProductCategory(budget_val));
```

Now in my database adapter i creadted a table and inserting those values as below:

```
public void topinchartsRecord(ProductCategory productCategory) {
    try{
        insertRecords(productCategory.getBudget_val(), SQLITE_TABLE3);
        }catch (Exception e) {
                    String LOG_TAG = "mylog";
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error reporting", e);
        }}

private void insertRecords(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> budget_val,
        String sqliteTable3) {

     if (budget_val != null && budget_val.size() > 0) {

        ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < budget_val.size(); i++) {
            con.clear();
            HashMap<String, String> row = budget_val.get(i);
            Iterator<String> it = row.keySet().iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {

                String columnName = it.next();
                con.put(columnName, row.get(columnName));
            }

            mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE3, null, con);
 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error reporting");
        System.out.println("Control entered last line of  the insert record=========== 3");
        }}}
```

But my database is showing nothing, no errors in trace: please let me know whether i am doing it right?

Comment: no errors because there is no log in your catch block.

Comment: You have an empty catch block. Could you log something there, and see if you get any errors?

Comment: @njzk2 it is entering into the insertRecords() block..anyway i am checking with log

Comment: i updated  now with log in catch block.. but nothing showing

Comment: also log the return value of the mDb.insert call

Comment: also, define "database is showing nothing"

Comment: @njzk2 i have put a log ana print statement after the insert statement, both are not logging in trace..so the insert code is wrong?

Comment: @ database not showinf meand i mean the data, its creating the table but no values are inserted

Comment: so, it doesn't reach the end of the method, but there is no exception raised. are you sure you even enter this method?

Comment: have you tried step-by-step debugging ?

Comment: @ yeah it is entering the method, but not the for loop